# How to provide access to a specific image in gcloud gcr.io?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, docker-registry, google-iam

I have created docker image with name `us.gcr.io/my-project/my-image` and I want to create service account which will have permission to pull & push only this specific docker image.

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control

As I understood I need to provide access to the whole bucket where all images are stored. Is it possible to set up permissions on specific image without creating a new google project (the only way i see now)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it directly with Google Container Registry. If you provide the Storage object viewer role to a service account, it can see all the images in all your container registry.

However, you can do it with [Artifact repository](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/manage-repos). For this

- Create a new repository
- Select your repository and click sur add member
- Add your service account and grand the role Artifact Repository Reader

[image]

Then you can access to your image (or you can push it), to this path

```
<location>-docker.pkg.dev/<ProjectId>/<RepositoryName>/<ImageName>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide permissions for a service account to an specific image (object) inside the bucket, this can be done through [fine-grained access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#choose_between_uniform_and_fine-grained_access), you would have to give the permissions cited on the URL you pointed:

**For Push (Read and Write)**

- storage.buckets.create
- storage.buckets.delete
- storage.buckets.get
- storage.buckets.list
- storage.buckets.update
- storage.objects.create
- storage.objects.delete
- storage.objects.get
- storage.objects.list
- storage.objects.update

**Pull (Read Only)**

- storage.objects.get
- storage.objects.list

Since I assume that you have your bucket already created, you can turn your default (Uniform) permissions to Fine grained, by following the next steps:

1. Open the Cloud Storage browser in the Google Cloud Console.
2. Click the Bucket overflow menu (the one with three points vertically aligned) associated with the bucket to which you want to grant a member a role.
3. Choose Edit bucket permissions.
4. If the right menu opened says "Uniform: No object-level ACLs enabled" click on "SWITCH TO FINE-GRAINED" then in the opened popup select "Fine Grained" and click on save.

Try to do it before 90 days have passed after the creation of your bucket, otherwise uniform permissions will be permanently and you will need to create a new bucket.

Comment: There are only docker layers stored in the bucket with sha256 names. So it's pretty hard if possible to provide fine-grained access to read images. And it will require to update the policy n every push to the registry.